# Form field "checkboxes" mutliple default values

Tags: extensions, form-fields-types, fields

When using a form field in an extension, you can normally define a default value, for example with a radio button:

```
<field name="something" type="radio" class="btn-group" default="1" label="Something">
    <option value="0">JOFF</option>
    <option value="1">JON</option>
</field>
```

This will ensure that the second option is automatically checked.

Now, I am using the `checkboxes` form field like so:

```
<field name="something" type="checkboxes" default="0" multiple="true" label="Something">
    <option value="0">Val 0</option>
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="4">Val 4</option>
</field>
```

As you can see, I've used `default="0"` which auto checks the first checkbox.

However I'd like to have all of them checked by default.

I've tried comma separating the default values and also tried a json string but with no avail.

If this possible by default or would I need to create an override for the `checkboxes` layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a comma separated property "checked" in the XML file rather than using default and you should be good. We also do not call trim on the comma separated values as having spaces in values is allowed by the W3C spec. So ensure there are no surplus spaces :)

Comment: Ah, yup that works. Cheers mate. Just a note that the comma separated values must not have a space. e.g this **will not** work: `checked="bold, italic"` but this **will** `checked="bold,italic"`

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this :)